# Bash - how to remove trailing "/bin/java" in commandline?

Tags: bash, command-line, awk

I cannot work this out, seems my command in awk is not good enough:

Basically I'd like to extract information from a simple Linux ls -l:

```
ls -l /etc/alternatives/java

lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 29 Apr  5 12:28 /etc/alternatives/java -> /jre/IBM/JDK6SR10FP1/bin/java
```

I then use awk to retrieve this part:

```
 ls /etc/alternatives/java -l | awk -F"->" '{print $2}'
 /jre/IBM/JDK6SR10FP1/bin/java
```

As I need to remove the trailing /bin/java to make it a valid $JAVA_HOME, how to do that in bash?

All I want is:

```
/jre/IBM/JDK6SR10FP1
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to look into using `readlink` from the GNU coreutils package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you assigned this value `/jre/IBM/JDK6SR10FP1/bin/java` to `JAVA_HOME` using command substitution:

```
JAVA_HOME=$(ls /etc/alternatives/java -l | awk -F"->" '{print $2}')
```

---

Update: as pointed out in the comments, `readlink` is the right tool to use for this step, not `ls`.

---

then you can remove the trailing part using

```
JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME%/bin/java}
```

For more information, see, for example the section [Manipulating Strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and working response, I will leave it there for sometime just to see if there are other options

Comment: just a side note: I need to run sed command to trim off leading and trailing whitespace from awk. But overall a nice and simple solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @tripleee In general it may be a good advise to be careful parsing `ls` output, but for this particular case, with only one line of output and the specific `->` separator used, I do not see how this could go wrong.

Comment: A file named `foo->bar` would be one example. There's of course a limit to how much time you are willing to spend on robustness around corner cases; but the simple solution is to use `readlink` which doesn't have them.

Comment: of course -- thanks for pointing this out. Additionally, the technique of removing the trailing part did not exactly work either so I wanted to remove this answer, but I can't because it is the accepted answer.

Comment: By the way, the duplicate that you (@tripleee) associated this question with does not address the removal of the trailing part, which seemed to be the aspect that the OP was asking about.

Comment: Oh well, I'll add a second duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the `JAVA_HOME` path from the Java path by removing the trailing `/bin/java` you can use `sed` (and [`readlink`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readlink.html) to resolve symbolic links):

```
JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /etc/alternatives/java | sed 's/\/bin\/java$//')
```

The regular expression in `sed` matches trailing `/bin/java`.

Alternatively (if not using `alternatives`):

```
JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f $(which java) | sed 's/\/bin\/java$//')
```